# How to solve the Fatal error on SEO

Tags: php, curl

Currently am working with my website to optimize it for search engines.

I'm getting the following error:

```
[home] [stats] [search website] [index website] [create tables] [configure] 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No pages indexed.

Index website

Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in E:\wamp\www\SEO\distribution\api\api.php on line 20
```

I don't know how to resolve the problem. Do I need to install the curl lib function, or something else? How can I resolve this error?

Comment: yes you have to enable curl with php

Comment: SEO has encountered a fatal error, problem, unhandled exception, crash, undefined behaviour, error-list, challenge, bug, "it worked on *my* machine".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`url_init()` function](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) is a part of [cURL extension](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) which is not available by default in PHP.

You have to install that extension. If you're not a server administrator then you probably can't do anything but ask him/her to do that.

However there is a workaround. cURL is just a abstract layer over HTTP protocol. If you know how [HTTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http) works you can write your own cURL using [`fsockopen() function`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php).

Answer (score 3):

Install and enable curl
http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

Is curl is installed on your server? Use php_info() function or check directly with your host provider.

Answer (score 0):

Its telling you that [curl_init()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) is undefined so it'll need figured out why.  You'd probably want a PHP coder to look at this for you.